# rails 4 rbenv bundle not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 4.2.4 app with Ruby 2.2.3 and Capistrano 3 to a VPS server.  I've done this several times before with RVM and had no problems with my other apps, but now I'm using rbenv on a new machine and also on the server and I get a stacktrace as follows:

```
DEBUG [a326a4c8] Command: cd /home/deploy/myapp/releases/20151226231303 && /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /home/deploy/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [a326a4c8]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [a326a4c8]    bundle: No such file or directory
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@youspoof.us: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@youspoof.us: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
```

I installed rbenv and ruby 2.2.3 global on my server as my deploy user.  Also did a `gem install bundler` and it installed.  From the server I run `bundle -v` and get `Bundler version 1.11.2` so I know bundler is installed.  I know ruby is using the rbenv shim ruby as when I issue a `which ruby` I get `/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby`.

I'm not sure exactly what's happening here as it's been a while since I've used rbenv.  Here is my capfile and deploy.rb if it helps.

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.3p173'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'
set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:shakycode/myapp.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

I may be missing something but every time I try to run `cap production deploy` I get the debug error about /usr/bin/env bundle no such file or directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  In the meantime I'll keep googling.

Answer (score 7):

Was able to sole this myself

## capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
```

## deploy.rb

```
set :rbenv_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv/'
```

Comment: You can use `set :rbenv_type, :user` instead of setting the rbenv path if you want.

Comment: @will_in_wi thanks I actually have them both set.  Should I remove the path and just leave rbenv_type?